# Is the hit and damage bonus the same as the +X of a magical weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Some magical weapons can be upgraded (for example from +1 to +2, etc.) and magical weapons also add an enhancement bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls.

Are the attack and damage added equal to the +X of the weapon? for example, if it is a +2 weapon, does it add a +2 to attack rolls and +2 damage?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

A +X weapon adds +X to attack and damage rolls, in every edition of DnD I'm aware of.

4e Player's Handbook, page 232:

> A magic weapon adds an enhancement bonus to attack
>   rolls and damage rolls, so a +3 flameburst longbow adds
>   +3 to all attack rolls and damage rolls made with the
>   bow.