# What does the +X on a magic weapon apply to?

Tags: magic-items, weapons, adnd-1e

What does the e.g. +1 on a magic longsword count for in Advanced Dungeons & Dragons? Is it a bonus to damage, or is it to attack?

Comment: [Related: D&D 4e] [Is the hit and damage bonus the same as the +X of a magical weapon?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45363)

Comment: Amazing thank you and sorry for the confusion especially since you took time to answer this even though you didn't have too.

Comment: No worries! But that's just a link to a similar question about a different edition. It doesn't quite answer this question, but I'm sure we'll see some answers roll in for this before long. Welcome to the site, meanwhile! Maybe check out the [tour] while this is waiting for answers to be submitted.

Answer (score 17):

## Both!

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1979) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* says that

> All magic swords receive their stated bonus both for purposes of hitting (as a bonus to the "to hit" die) and for damage (as +1, +2, +3, etc. addition to hit points of damage scored). (165)

Thus, consider a fighter armed with a *longsword +1, +2 vs. magic-using and enchanted creatures*:

- Against mundane creatures, the fighter rolls 1d20 to hit and, because of that *sword*, adds +1 to the result.
- If he hits and deals damage with the same *sword*, he rolls the *sword*'s damage and adds +1 point of damage (in addition to any other modifiers).

Further, if he's facing, say, an annoying unicorn, then (because of the *+2 vs. magic-using and enchanted creatures*) the fighter instead rolls 1d20 +2 to hit, and, if he hits, adds +2 to the damage dealt by the sword.